# What is the spell shillelagh? And how does it make a weapon +1?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, weapons

It says in the description that it makes a cudgel or quarterstaff "+1" what does this mean? Are there other ways to "level up" a weapon? How would it affect its use? I'm sorry for all the questions just nothing really explains it to me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does a magic weapon's plus apply to?](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/55052/what-does-a-magic-weapons-plus-apply-to)

Comment: Hint: go read the magic weapon section of the book.

Comment: Have you had a look at the full [spell description](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/s/shillelagh)? It is much more detailed than the short description you seem to be citing.

Comment: Flagged as dupe (of the one question I could find offhand that asks what a +1 means, even though it's tagged 5e); we need a canonical question for this one, folks!

Comment: Not a dupe because that Q is for 5e and this one for Pathfinder. The canonical question for this one is "read your game book."

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this can be answered by reading the spell section and magic weapon section of the book.

Comment: @MadMAxJr I understand, but I'm voting to leave open (I'm in the review queue at the moment) because the meta consensus disagrees that close-votes are the right tool for this kind of question. ([Can we have a RTFM equivalent in the Vote to Close options?](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/4825/can-we-have-a-rtfm-equivalent-in-the-vote-to-close-options))

Comment: Yes close it or do whatever. I'm using the app on an iPad. So I don't have the book. I'm sorry for "not being aware enough" too just instinctively know where to go to look these questions up. I asked because I was confused and overloaded at the time get off my damn back. I didn't know this was a place where new players were shunned sorry.

Comment: @Ocean: In general it isn't, but questions that could have easily been answered without posting them at all are not favored, because they create work for no purpose and with little benefit. That is one of the reasons downvotes were included in the SE software to begin with.

Comment: Don't worry I won't be wasting any work on this site again

Comment: @Ocean If you've read the book and have a specific question, we're a great place for new players.  What we don't do is read the book to you.  For Pathfinder, you can even get "the book" for free (legally) by using the System Reference Document, available at http://www.d20pfsrd.com.  For your specific question, you're probably looking for either the Spells section (for *shillelagh* and spells like it, like *lead blades* or *magic weapon*) and the [Magic Items](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/magic-weapons) section (which explains how magic weapons work).

Answer (score 5):

It's just [what it says](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/s/shillelagh). It takes a cudgel or quarterstaff in your possession and temporarily makes it a +1 magical weapon. That's the only effect and it lasts as long as the spell. There are a number of other spells such as [Magic Weapon](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/m/magic-weapon) or [Returning Weapon](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/r/returning-weapon) that can temporarily modify a weapon with various bonuses and abilities. The one thing all these spells have in common is they are temporary. Once the spell ends, so does the effect.

For permanent effect, a weapon must be [crafted as magical](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/magic-weapons). The rules and variety of weapons are too in depth to go into here.

Comment: Thank you! I'm sorry it was such a "bad" question Im just new to this whole scene and didn't know what to look for..

Answer (score 1):

A Weapon "+1" is a common magic weapon, many of those in tons of variants can be found in Pathfinder, and the Rule Book actually has the rules for those weapons in it and how they affect the weapons. (Take a look at the "magic weapons" part of the book which I can't quote, as I only own it in german).

I can't tell you much about other ways to "level up" a weapon, but they surely exist. (there are some spells that do so, and you can learn to create magic weapons)

This way, the "shillelagh" spell requires you to either wield a quarterstaff or a club, and enhances its damage (by changing it's effective size when rolling damage) as well as making it a magical weapon +1